# Add movieclip to Index

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to add a movieclip to an index in AS3 ?

I have been trying to use AddChild in order but it doesnt work, is there a way I can add Certain Object to specific Index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply Add `addChildAt (mc , index)` not just `addChild(mc)`

Answer (score 2):

DisplayObjectContainer has several ways to manipulate its child z-position:

> **swapChildren**(child1:DisplayObject, child2:DisplayObject)

- will swap the z-order (front-to-back order) of the two specified child objects

> **swapChildrenAt**(index1:int, index2:int)

- will swap the z-order (front-to-back order) of the child objects at the two specified index positions in the child list

> **setChildIndex**(child:DisplayObject, index:int)

- will change z-position of a child in the display object container

> **addChildAt**(child:DisplayObject, index:int)

- adds a child to specified position

---

You can find **more info** [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)